# How to add an S3 trigger for lambda

Tags: python, sam

I want to add an S3 trigger event to my lambda function. For some reason it doesn't work

```
Resources:
      SecondFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
        Properties:
          CodeUri: second/
          Handler: app.lambda_handler
          Runtime: python3.8
          Policies:
            - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
                TableName: "test_table"
          Events:
            S3Bucket:
              Type: S3
              Properties:
                Bucket: !Ref PracticeBucket
                Events: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
      PracticeBucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```